# error creating jar file

Tags: java, jar

when I run my java project in eclipse by run main method it work properly.but when I create an executable jar file from that and run it, it didn't work properly.what is the reason for that.there is no error massages.
my application is a swing application. in interface of the application has images.when I create the jar file and run it.some images are not loading.please help me.

Comment: Define "didn't work properly".  You need to be much more specific if you want someone to be able to help you.

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Comment: Nobody here can magically know what the problem is. Try to launch the file through the console and give us any output: `java -jar path/to/your/file.jar`

Comment: my application is a swing application.when I create a jar file and run it,some images of the interface are not loading.

Comment: @lakshman: Pretend you were trying to answer the question yourself. Do you think "some images of the interface are not loading" would be enough information? What have you already tried? What's happening instead? Where are these images? Have you checked whether they're being included in the jar file?

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/122909

Comment: @lakshman: *"I create an executable jar file from that and run it,.."*  Make sure you run it from the command line so that any errors will appear.  Also make sure the code does not hide exception information.  For every `Throwable` that is caught in a `catch`, call `printStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably didn't create the correct manifest file to add to your JAR.  You need to specify what the main class is and what the classpath will be.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  given the amount of info in the question it's a good guess.

Comment: You are pretty much speculating.

Comment: Yes, I am.   But why is that a bad guess?  If the OP doesn't know about manifest, because Eclipse is hiding it from them, it's a perfectly good answer.

Comment: I would suggest to get more info from the asker with a comment before throwing wild guesses.

Comment: You're correct, but that doesn't mean this answer is harmful.  It can always been modified when new information becomes available.  Until that happens, this can be useful.

Comment: Ten years later the answer is accepted?  What took so long?